# Python Regular Expression pattern

Tags: python, regex, file

I am renaming all of the files in a directory, and using a regex pattern to check if any of the files have a the appropriate file-name structure (I double checked the pattern on www.rubular.com, and it seemed to be correct). If so, it skips renaming he file. The following code renames the file regardless if it has the appropriate file-name structure .... I'm not seeing why it does not skip over the file. Any help in determining why the regex pattern is not working will be appreciated:

```
# Appropriate file name: P.002-night.jpg; File name to rename: bird.jpg


import os, os.path
import re


def displaymatch(match):
    if match is None:
        return None
    return '<Match: %r, groups=%r>' % (match.group(), match.groups())

sampledir = "c:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\New folder"
os.chdir(sampledir)
FileList = os.listdir(os.getcwd())


num = 000

pattern = r"\w.\d{3}\-\w+.(jpg|Jpg|JPG)"


for filename in FileList:
    if displaymatch(re.match(pattern, filename)) != None:
        pass
    else:
        os.rename(filename, "P." + str("{0:0=3d}".format(num)) + "-" + filename)
        num+= 1
```

Comment: You have an `r` at the start of your pattern. As an aside, rubular is designed for ruby, you can use http://pythex.org for the re module of python.

Comment: Presumably you meant that to be a raw string (`r""`) rather than a string starting with r (`"r"`). Why are you using both `str.endswith` *and* `re.match`?

Comment: ah yeah, Casimir has it. It's common in python to put an r _outside_ the string when defining regexes, which makes it a "raw string," so backslash-escaping will be easier. You want `r"[a-zA-Z]\.\d{3}\-[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(jpg|Jpg|JPG)"`

Comment: why don't you just check for a match instead of checking for a non match and a match?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That was an oversight on my part.

Comment: What is an example of **apropriate** filename for you and what is not?...Give us examples?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour- I updated my question with this info. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments, I updated the code and it now works as I expected.

Comment: Just use `if displaymatch(re.match(pattern, filename)):os.rename...` and forget the rest

Comment: @PadraicCunningham When I tried that, it did not work. Actually, it renamed the files that already had the appropriate file name structure, but did not rename the file names to be renamed.

Comment: sorry yes, `if displaymatch(re.match(pattern, filename)) is None:os....`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
pattern = r"\w.\d{3}\-\w+.(jpg|Jpg|JPG)"


for filename in FileList:
    if displaymatch(re.match(pattern, filename)) is None:
        os.rename(filename, "P." + str("{0:0=3d}".format(num)) + "-" + filename)
        num+= 1
```